# Open Graph Actions - getting past pre-approval errors thrown by FB

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

To get Open Graph action running against my app this is what I'm trying to do:

1. Create the actions and the objects
2. Create the object metafile
3. Publish the actions

   - This didn't work for the Admin itself because too many errors got generated by FB
   - Errors were generated since the actions weren't approved and publishing those actions was failing for my current user base.

To get around the errors (which is blocking the approval of my actions from FB), I blocked out my user base from publishing the actions and put filters in for the Admin, developers and testers (that is, only publish requests originating from these accounts go through)

Is there a better way of getting this done?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. The actions should only be enabled for test users / admins / devs of the application until Facebook has approved the action. However, if the publish action fails, you should fail gracefully in any case. The user shouldn't know there was an error, but you should log it for debugging later on.